# Modifying project properties of custom project system in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsx, vspackage

I have tried to create a custom project system by walk through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc512961.aspx and succeeded. And now I want to modify the project properties of this created project system. The second part of this walk through is guiding to create property pages for solution properties. (Solution Explorer-> Right Click on Solution and select Properties) I don't want to modify solution properties, I need to customize project properties (Solution Explorer-> Right Click on Project and select Properties) by adding new tabs and other items for my custom project system. Please help me as soon as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project system is based on `MPF` custom tab pages can be integrated via the `ProjectNode` class. This class defines the `GetConfigurationIndependentPropertyPages` and `GetConfigurationDependentPropertyPages` methods; those are virtual methods and can be implemented by any derived type to return the type-id´s of `IPropertyPage` implementations.

```
internal class CustomProjectNode : ProjectNode
{
    protected override Guid[] GetConfigurationIndependentPropertyPages()
    {
        return new[] 
        {
            typeof(MyCustomPropertyPage).Guid
        };
    }
}
```

The `IPropertyPage` interface is the connector between the project system and the UI allowing to change properties, whereby the UI is an ordenary window (usually a Windows Forms `Control`). The property page implementation must be marked with the `ComVisible`- and `ClassInterface`-attributes, and optionally with a `Guid`-attribute, if one wants to keep control over the type-guid.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("...")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
internal class MyCustomPropertyPage : IPropertyPage
{
    ...
}
```

In addition the property page type must be exposed through the `ProvideObject`-attribute on the package class.

```
[ProvideObject(typeof(MyCustomPropertyPage))]
class MyPackage : Package
{
}
```

Finally, to make the property page appear as a tab the `SupportsProjectDesigner` property of the custom project node must be set to `true`.

```
internal class CustomProjectNode : ProjectNode
{
    public CustomProjectNode() 
    {
        this.SupportsProjectDesigner = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matze,
Very thanks for your update. I have made all the above things except the last step. I'm unable to set the SupportsProjectDesigner to true. In which class I have to use this code. Please provide me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MathivananKP It´s a virtual property which is defined by the `ProjectNode` class. You can find it here: https://mpfproj12.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Dev12/Src/CSharp/ProjectNode.cs So, just derive your project node from that type - and the code (as shown above) should work... Btw, please accept the answer, if the solution works for you (-;